# How do extract child element in XML using DOM in PHP 5.0?

Tags: php, xml

I am having the XML like this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <root>
      <mynode catid="10" catname="Animals" label="Animals" catdesc="" parent_id="2">
         <mynode catid="11" catname="Lions" label="Lions" catdesc="" parent_id="10">
           <mynode catid="12" catname="lion" label="lion" catdesc="" parent_id="11"/>
         <mynode catid="13" catname="lioness" label="lioness" catdesc="" parent_id="11"/>
        </mynode>
       </mynode>
    </root>
```

From this I want to remove

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
```

and

```
</root>
```

So expected result is

```
        <mynode catid="10" catname="Animals" label="Animals" catdesc="" parent_id="2">
         <mynode catid="11" catname="Lions" label="Lions" catdesc="" parent_id="10">
           <mynode catid="12" catname="lion" label="lion" catdesc="" parent_id="11"/>
         <mynode catid="13" catname="lioness" label="lioness" catdesc="" parent_id="11"/>
        </mynode>
       </mynode>
```

How can I do this?

Edit 1:TO Phil

```
        $dom = new DomDocument();
       //$dom->preserveWhitespace = false;
     $dom->load('treewithchild.xml'); 

function DOMinnerHTML($element) 
{ 
$innerHTML = ""; 
$children = $element->childNodes; 

foreach ($children as $child) 
{ 

    $tmp_dom = new DOMDocument(); 
    $tmp_dom->appendChild($tmp_dom->importNode($child, true)); 
    $innerHTML.=trim($tmp_dom->saveXML()); 
    echo $tmp_dom->saveXML();
} 
return $innerHTML; 
 } 
  $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

  $domTable = $dom->getElementsByTagName("mynode"); 

    foreach ($domTable as $tables) 
   { 
//echo $tables;
       DOMinnerHTML($tables); 
  }
```

Comment: @phil In my case I am getting an XML not an HTML.It didnt work for me

Comment: Use saveXML() instead of saveHTML()

Comment: @phil I tried that I didnt get anything when I print `echo $tmp_dom->saveXML();`?Is there anything need to change

Comment: Sorry for leading you down what appears to be an overly complex path. I've added an answer below which is much more straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want the inner markup of the `<root>` node, that is the element who's child nodes you'll want to iterate. You can access this element using the `DOMDocument::documentElement` property.

Try this (tested and working)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->load('treewithchild.xml');
$inner = '';
foreach ($doc->documentElement->childNodes as $child) {
    $inner .= $doc->saveXML($child);
}
echo $inner;
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that the root element is returned also, you have to know that for each xml file an  is added impliicitly, even if it exists in your file. so try to do this
    $children = $element->childNodes->childNodes; 
i think that would help you.

Comment: Could you please explain briefly or give any sample code.Because that method didnt work for me